# Drupal modal does not render remote forms (Mautic)

Tags: theming, javascript, modal-dialogs

I'm trying to embed Mautic forms in my drupal site.
I created a controller pointing to '/mautic-form` and in the twig template I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//mautic.coachingrealista.com/mautic/form/generate.js?id=3"></script>
```

[image]

When I go to that page (`/mautic-form`), the form renders well:
[image]

But when I use it inside a modal, it does not render that form:

```
<a data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:800}" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/mautic-form" class="use-ajax">LEARN MORE</a>
```

[image]

I looked on the JS console and I didn't see any error.

It's doing fine with the requests:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just wanted to give some feedback: I see you already posted this as a bug to mautics github issue. Just tested it on one of my local sites and I can also confirm that the form itself is rendered in the `<head>`when added to a modal.

Comment: yes, I'll post an answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that it is a Mautic issue, I posted it in the Mautic GitHub issue:
https://github.com/mautic/mautic/issues/10563

Actually, the form is generated but in the head so I did a walkaround moving the form from there to the div where I wanted to be with JS.